# Passar Array String por parâmetro

Tags: java

```
public List<String> Matriz(){

    String CaminhoArquivo=("C:\\Users\\jessica borges"
            + "\\Downloads\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
            + "\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
            + "\\CalculadoraMatrizes\\src\\ArquivosMatriz\\matrix.txt");

    List<String> conteudo = new ArrayList<>(); 
        try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CaminhoArquivo));
        String linha;
        while ((linha = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            conteudo.addAll(Arrays.asList(linha.split(" ")));
        }   
         in.close();             
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
            }

        System.out.println(conteudo);             
        return conteudo;     
}
```

Esse método acima adiciona o que eu quero na array, quero tratar o retorno dele em outro método que segue abaixo:

```
public void Matriz22(){


}
```

Já tentei vários modos porém não conseguir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o método Matriz22 receber uma lista de String é assim:

```
public void Matriz22(List<String> lista){

}
```

Você não mostrou a classe ao qual pertence o método Matriz() então improvisei, para passar a lista de retorno do método Matriz() faz assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Classe classe = new Classe();
    List<String> lista = classe.Matriz();
    classe.Matriz22(lista);
}
```